# Group rows of a table by a column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this table:

```
Id  Title   BugNumber
--- ------- ---------
1    row1      224
2    row2      321
3    row3      224
4    row4      123
```

I want to group the rows by *BugNumber* and show them in a View like:

```
Bug 224
--------
   1 row1
   3 row3

Bug 321
-------
   2 row2

Bug 123
-------
   4 row4
```

Model:

```
public class MyTable
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int? BugNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult MyGroupView()
{
    using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
    {
        db.MyTable.GroupBy(r => r.BugNumber);
        // ??? 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in this but i don't think you can do that with a group by. A group by aggregates data and is useful when you want to do things like sum, count... I suggest that instead, you order the rows by "bug number, id" and then while you loop over your items, whenever the bug number changes, you create a new section. I don' know if there are any alternatives but also keeping in mind that 1 query that gets all the data is usually better than many queries that get a subset of it

Comment: @DanyKhalife Thanks. I think this the answer to my question.

Comment: Glad i could help, i'll post it as an answer so you can mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in this but i don't think you can do that with a group by.

A group by aggregates data and is useful when you want to do things like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG`...

I suggest that instead, you order the rows by `bug number, id`. This way you will have batches of rows that have the same bug number one after the other and each batch will be sorted by the column `id`

Then, when you loop over your items, whenever the bug number changes, it means you got a new batch, so you simply create a new section.

I don' know if there are any alternatives specifically to your case with C# , Linq and EF but keep in mind that 1 query that gets all the data is usually better than many queries that get a subset of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use `GroupBy`. It's example how to do this with two class and one selection query.

```
public class MyTable
{
    public int? Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public int? BugNumber {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format(" {0}, {1}, {2}", Id, Title, BugNumber.Value);
    }
}
public class MyTableGroup
{
    public int? BugNumber {get;set;}
    public List<MyTable> Values{get;set;}
}
var data = new List<MyTable>()
{
    new MyTable() { Id = 1, Title = "row1", BugNumber=224 },
    new MyTable() { Id = 2, Title = "row2", BugNumber=321 },
    new MyTable() { Id = 3, Title = "row3", BugNumber=224 },
    new MyTable() { Id = 4, Title = "row4", BugNumber=123 }
};
var result = new List<MyTableGroup>();
var groupResult = data.GroupBy(s => s.BugNumber);
 foreach (var group in groupResult)
 {
     result.Add(new MyTableGroup()
     {
         BugNumber = group.Key,
         Values = group.ToList()
     });
 }
//display result for console app:
result.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine("\n key: {0}\n, Values: \n\t {1}\n", r.BugNumber, string.Join(", \n\t", r.Values)));
```